# What conclusions can be drawn about the ideal generated by these polynomials?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

so this is my computational algebra homework: consider the system

$f(x,y,z)=3x +5y+9z=3$

$g(x)= 3x^5 +8x^3 +12x^2 +8x+7=0$

$h(x,y)=4x^2*y^3 +8x^3*y^2 +7x+9y+5=0$

first i had to show there's a single solution to the system. so far so good.

the next question is what conclusions can be drawn for the ideal genereated by the three polynomials on the ring $R[x,y]$
i think that in order to compute the ideal i need to find the common dividers of $f,g,h$ but my abstract algebra knowledge is limited to finding dividers for single variable polynomials only

Comment: I think you mean the ring $R[X,Y,Z]$ (with the $Z$)

Comment: i think so too but that's what my professor has posted. perhaps a typo

Comment: I think the conclusions to be drawn are related to the solution you found in the first step.

Comment: well yes, but how?

Comment: Is R algebraically closed ? Have you heard of Hilbert's Nullstellensatz ? If the polynomial system has a unique solution in its algebraic closure then the ideal generated by f,g,h has a very simple expression.

Comment: The system is considered over $\Bbb Q$? Over $\Bbb C$? The equation $g(x) =0$  has one solution ($x=1$) over $\Bbb Q$ and five in $\Bbb C$. For each such solution we obtain an equation of degree three in $y$, $h(x,y)=0$,  so there are so far $5\cdot 3$ solutions over $\Bbb C$. (Bezout would make this clear from the start.) None is rational. So what does it mean "*there's a single solution*"? The question "*what conclusion can be drawn*" is not really a clear question. We can of course explicitly compute the ideal, and e.g. the ideal obtained after elimination of $x,z$, which is principal...